# iOS - Swift - sync and async

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

Please help me to solve this problem - after a lot of (not so efficent...) search I can't do this alone.

I have the following methods:

```
showLoadingAnimation()
```

to show the loading animation while background tasks are running

```
hideLoadingAnimation()
```

to hide the loading animation as soon as all the background tasks are finished

```
getUserFacebookData()
```

to get Facebook-user data

```
uploadUserFacebookDataToServer()
```

to upload the Facebook-user data to the server (and perform tasks with them).

What I want to perform:

1. Show up the loading animation: **showLoadingAnimation()**
2. Get the user data from Facebook: **getFacebookData()**

   - Wait until these data are being downloaded
3. As soon as the Facebook-user data are being download, upload these data to the server: **uploadUserFacebookDataToServer()**

   - Wait untile these data are being uploaded
4. Hide the loading animation: **hideLoadingAnimation()**

Now my problem is, that I don't know how to solve this problem. I know, that I should use *sync* and/or *async* tasks, *GCD*... But I don't know how, and I can't find a proper guide to it.

Could someone explain it to me through these functions?
Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Thank you, Zhi-Wei Cai, that was the kind of answer what I was hoping for.

Now it seems to work, the calling order is OK, 
but now the problem is the same as the beginning:

```
uploadUserFacebookDataToServer()
```

doesn't wait until

```
getUserFacebookData
```

downloads the user data from Facebook, that's why it won't be able to work with the necessary data given back from

```
getUserFacebookData
```

Any idea? Is there anything to do with dispatch?

**UPDATE 2:**

As you requested, here are the fuctions. I hope, with these information you can help me to solve this problem and to understand this whole process.

```
func getFacebookUserData(completionHandler: () -> Void)
{
    println("getFacebookUserData")

    let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

        if ((error) != nil)
        {
            // Process error
            println("Error: \(error)")
        }
        else
        {
            let userID : NSString = result.valueForKey("id") as NSString!

            var defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            defaults.setObject(userID, forKey: "settings_facebookID")
            self.facebookID_fromSettings = userID
        }
    })
```

and

```
func getObjectIDfromFacebookID(completionHandler: () -> Void)
{
    println("getObjectIDfromFacebookID")

    var query = PFQuery(className:"users")
    query.whereKey("facebookID", equalTo:facebookID_fromSettings)
    println("getObjectIDfromFacebookID: facebookID: " + facebookID_fromSettings)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
                println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
            // Do something with the found objects

            if (objects!.count == 0) {
                // New user, registering
                println("New user, registering")
            }
            else
            {
                //User is already regsitered, reading out objectID
                println("User is already regsitered, reading out objectID")
            }

            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
                    println("objectID: " + object.objectId)

                    var objectID: String = object.objectId
                    println(objectID)

                    var defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
                    defaults.setObject(objectID, forKey: "settings_objectID")
                }
            }

        }
    }
    completionHandler()
}
```

So the first function gets the facebookID from the FB-server, but this process takes time, it won't give a result immediately. The second function should work with this data, that's why it should "wait" until the first gives back the requested data.

I can solve this problem by building these 2 fuctions together in one, but that's "not elegant", and I also would like to use this (sync/async dispatch) method in other parts of the project,

Thanks for trying to help me!

Comment: Are `getFacebookData()` and `uploadUserFacebookDataToServer()` synchronous or asynchronous? Do they have a conpletion handler or not? Show the declaration of those methods please

Comment: At this point they are just simple functions, without any parameters or special properties (like completion handler). I'm stucked, so I don't want to mess things up, that's why I keep it as simple now as possible. And hopefully after your help I will be able extend them.

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: No, I just uploaded the requested information to you (the functions).

Answer (score 2):

You can use **completion handlers**:

```
   func showLoadingAnimation() {
        self.getUserFacebookData({ () -> Void in
            self.uploadUserFacebookDataToServer({ () -> Void in
                self.hideLoadingAnimation()
            })
        })
    }

    func getUserFacebookData(completionHandler: () -> Void) {
        println("getUserFacebookData")
        completionHandler()
    }

    func uploadUserFacebookDataToServer(completionHandler: () -> Void) {
        println("uploadUserFacebookDataToServer")
        completionHandler()
    }

    func hideLoadingAnimation() {
        println("hideLoadingAnimation")
    }
```

Once `showLoadingAnimation()` is called, the rest will be done asynchronously.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/Short_Practical_Guide_Blocks/

Comment: Thank you, Zhi-Wei Cai. I followed your advice, now the calling order is OK, but now other problem occoured. Please read my Update. Thank you!

Comment: I'd need to see the code of getUserFacebookData() to know what's going on. What connection class did you use? NSURLSession? NSURLConnection? One is async and one is sync. If it's async you'd need to put the next block into connection's completion handler block.

Answer (score 0):

**[EDIT]** Use `dispatch_group_t`
check following code

Step 1: showLoadingAnimation()

Step 2: `dispatch_group_t faceBookService = dispatch_group_create();`

Step 3:`dispatch_group_async_enter(faceBookService,queue,^{
   getUserFacebookData()
   // The below given line should be inside completion handler or after the above task has finished
   dispatch_group_leave(faceBookService);
});`

Step 4:`dispatch_group_async_enter(faceBookService,queue,^{
   uploadUserFacebookDataToServer()
   // The below given line should be inside completion handler or after the above task has finished
   dispatch_group_leave(faceBookService);
});`

Step 5:`dispatch_group_notify(faceBookService,dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
   //Called after finishing both tasks.
   hideLoadingAnimation()
});`

Comment: Hi Deepak Samuel Rajan, thanks for your answer, I'm going to check this solution as soon as possible!

Comment: I tried to enter your code, but Xcode (Swift) didn't accept it, I had to rewrite it. Could you please extend the code given by Zhi-Wei Cai to work with dispatch?